# Share Custom Text in Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, custom-font, android-typeface

How to share custom text with other apps in android?

On a TextView I have implemented TypeFace by `view.setTypeface(typeface);`

Now I want to share that text with typeface over another application via intent.
So I done the following:

```
            CharSequence text = textView.getText();
            Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
            sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
            sendIntent.setType("text/*");

            Intent shareIntent = Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, null);
            checkBox.setChecked(false);
            mContext.startActivity(shareIntent);
```

But the problem is I'm only getting the plain string not with the typeface.

i.e if I want to share

or
 
with other apps. But I'm ending of sharing
 `Example Text` 
with other apps.

Edit:
I have seen that in android there is a class `SpannableString` to store formatted string data with font family or typeface. This can be done by

```
SpannableString spannable = new SpannableString(textView.getText());
spannable.setSpan(myTypeface,0,textView.getText().toString().length()-1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

But still not able to find any way to share this with other apps.

Comment: where you want to share your typeface ?? is it in image format ??

Comment: I wanted to share the text with social media apps like whatsapp/ facebook/ instagram with custom font.

Comment: can you plz send the example of your text, how will it look like

Comment: ``` 

  ```                                                                                                                                      I want to share this kind of text with other apps

Comment: its unable to read bro send some screen shots